# How do i print the list of jobs per plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, groovy

I'm trying to list the jenkins jobs per plugin is being utilized. I see there's a plugin in jenkins, https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-usage-plugin, which displays the plugins usage in the Jenkins UI. But how do i get the same output from the groovy script?

Comment: i've a jenkins master and i'm trying list the jobs or builds that are being utilized by a particular plugin. Ex: how many jobs are configured/used by maven plugin

Comment: i was trying to test these scripts, support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216351528. In a similar way i want to list all the jobs configured with a particular plugin.

Answer (score 1):

They quick and dirty answer is to "[Display jobs group by the build steps they use](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Display+jobs+group+by+the+build+steps+they+use)" as updated below.

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.tasks.*

//All the projects on which we can apply the getBuilders method
def allProjects = Jenkins.instance.allItems.findAll{ it instanceof Project }

//All the registered build steps in the current Jenkins Instance
def allSteps = Builder.all()

//Group the projects by the build steps used
def projectsGroupBySteps = allSteps.inject([:]){
   map, step ->
   map[step.clazz.name] = allProjects.findAll{it.builders.any{ 
        it.class.name.contains(step.clazz.name)}}.collect{it.fullName}
   map
}

//Presentation
projectsGroupBySteps.sort().each{
    println "--- ($it.value.size) $it.key ---"
}
println ''

println 'Occcurences:'
projectsGroupBySteps.sort().each{
println "--- ($it.value.size) $it.key ---"
    it.value.each {
        println it }
    println ''
}
return
```

Note that a job has multiple sections: **builders**, **publishers** and **buildWrappers**.
Depending on what you are looking for, replace

```
[allSteps = Builder.all(), allProjects.findAll{it.builders.any ]
[allSteps = Publisher.all(), allProjects.findAll{it.publishers.any ]
[allSteps = BuildWrapper.all(), allProjects.findAll{it.buildWrappers.any ]
```

Plugins may also be involved in the **SCM** section and as **properties** (eg: `hudson.plugins.buildblocker.BuildBlockerProperty`, `com.sonyericsson.jenkins.plugins.bfa.model.ScannerJobProperty`)

Obviously, same limitations of plugin-usage apply: does not scan pipeline steps plugin usage or build steps nested within an `org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep`